# Wordpress recaptcha/captcha plugins are not downloading

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to download the wordpress recaptcha/captcha plugin but it can not be downloading.

Getting error on downloading "400 Bad Request".

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try downloading manually and importing them into your wordpress install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**400 Status Code Explained**

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications. The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled.

**Why it occurs**

A HTTP 400 bad request occurs whenever the web server terminates this search cycle and does not allow the client to get access to any particular information requested, owing to a particular reason. In the simplest term, a HTTP 400 bad request occurs when the web server turns down the request of the client to view any particular information, owing to the disobeying of the rules listed under the hypertext transfer protocol.

**fix**

This happens because of a problem on the client system e.g. there is something unstable on your PC running the Web browser. So there are a lot of things to check. If you are monitoring your website through 100pulse,you encounter 400 status code error through e-mail or Short message service.

Comment: Thanks,i got issue its because of antivirus blocking malware.